# Binding element 'children' implicitly has an 'any' type.ts(7031) in Next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, tsx

While developing my personal portfolio using Next.js, I ran into an error where the prop "children" was not working. I am using tsx.

Layout.tsx

```
import styles from "./layout.module.css";

export default function Layout({ children, ...props }) {
  return (
    <>
      <main className={styles.main} {...props}>{children}</main>
    </>
  );
}
```

I tried using other props, defining the props, like I was from tutorials online, but none of them worked. ;(

Comment: Those fragments (`<>`)  are not necessary. You can learn more here: https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your filetype is .tsx, which is a TypeScript filetype. You have to either define the types of the props, or change the file's name to Layout.js to convert it to vanilla JavaScript.

If you want to use TypeScript:

```
import { ReactNode } from "react";
import styles from "./layout.module.css";

const type LayoutProps = {
  children: ReactNode;
  // Your other props here.
}

export default function Layout({ children, ...props }: LayoutProps) {
  return (
    <>
      <main className={styles.main} {...props}>{children}</main>
    </>
  );
}
```

The issue is that when TypeScript doesn't know the `type` of something, it will assume the type is `any` and complain. You could explicitly set the type as `any` to solve this problem, as well, but this is considered bad practice:

```
export default function Layout({ children, ...props }: any) {
  return (
    <>
      <main className={styles.main} {...props}>{children}</main>
    </>
  );
}
```